# Is the average of two endpoint's instantaneous rates of change always the same as the average rate of change of the interval on a parabola?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

Is the average of two endpoint's instantaneous rates of change always the same as the average rate of change of the interval on a parabola? If not, which additional circumstances would cause it to always be the same?

EDIT: How would you verify this algebraically? Answered

EDIT 2: They both result in the same answer, but do they get their answer from the same line that touches/intercepts the graph, or do they get their answer from different lines (secant, tangent, etc.) that touch/intercept the graph, and because the two lines are always parallel to each other, they result in the same answer?

Comment: Yes. It's not hard to verify with a bit of algebra. The use of this fact becomes problematic in calculus when students try to invoke it for polynomials of degree higher than 2, or for non-polynomial functions. Students used to complain to me that "We learned in (high-school) physics that ..." forgetting that the position function of an object in straight line motion under constant acceleration is a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: Thank you for responding. How would you verify this with algebra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A parabola is the graph of a quadratic polynomial $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c.$ The average rate of change of $f$ on the interval $[r,s]$ is $\frac{f(s)-f(r)}{s-r}.$ You can check that this computes to $\frac{a(s^2-r^2)+b(s-r)}{s-r} = a(s+r)+b.$ The instantaneous rate of change of a function is its derivative $f'$. In this case $f'(x)=2ax+b,$ so the instantaneous rates at the endpoints are $f'(s)=2as+b$ and $f'(r)=2ar+b.$ The average of these two values is easily seen to be $a(s+r)+b,$ which is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a hint, but you need to know some calculus to understand the problem itself.

Recall that average value of a function $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$ is: $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

And the average of the two endpoints instantaneous rate of change is given by:

$$\frac{f'(b) + f'(a)}{2}$$

Where $f'(x)$ is the derivative at some point $x$.

Now think about a polynomial of the form $f(x) = x^2$. How would you go about showing the two expressions above are the same? And then you could do the same kind of algebraic manipulation for any parabola of the form $f(x) = a(x-h)^2 + k$ with $a,h,k$ some constants. It's just more algebra.

Comment: Thanks for your help. At the moment, I'm learning advanced functions, I do not have any understanding  of calculus. I'll try to get the answer with your hints and post back for confirmation.

Comment: @GaryGill, you're welcome. When you say instantaneous rate of change, you are talking calculus, more specifically the derivative. So if you aren't familiar with calculating the derivative, you won't be able to show this using just algebra. Calculus is another tool that you need first to approach this.